# Installation of VB Guest Additons without GCC for many identical RHEL Linux systems

Tags: linux, virtualbox, linux-kernel, rhel-6

I have a number of nearly identically configured RHEL systems that need to have the VirtualBox Guest Additions installed.  Unfortunately, the installation requires the addition of basically the development suite which is not installed since these machines are primarily supporting applications and package minimization is required.

Anybody done this before?

Initially, I have been pursuing hows to capture changed files on a control host and transfer this set between the two systems.  Kernel module addition seems to be an issue, the modules can be added but how to make them properly integrate into the system seems to be the issue.

Comment: Make a package, and install it everywhere. For example Debian already do this: compiles the source into a package, then installs the package, so you can simply copy this .deb to any identical host.

Comment: have you done this specific thing before?  I do understand how to package things.

Comment: my concern is the kernel modules